# Which TIdSMTP/SSLIOHandler event should trigger when TLS negotiation fails?

Tags: delphi, ssl, smtp, indy

I want to make SMTP TLS "implicit/explicit" configuration transparent, and to do this I thought of using event triggers.

My idea is just to capture if the TLS negotiation succeeds or fails and then try again with the other option.

I saw some events on `TIdSMTP` and `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`, but none of them seems to trigger correctly.

Documentation for Indy also can't be downloaded [here](https://www.indyproject.org/documentation/) (DNS broken error).

I used the following events with a "`Sleep(1);`" just to put a breakpoint in them.

> `TIdSMTP`:
>
> `OnTLSNotAvailable`
>
> `OnTLSHandShakeFailed`
>
> `OnTLSNegCmdFailed`
>
> `OnFailedEHLO`

> `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`:
>
> `OnStatus`
>
> `OnStatusInfo`
>
> `OnStatusInfoEx`

What I've tested:

I used for example Outlook **smtp.office365.com** with port **587** (which is `STARTTLS` - `utUseExplicitTLS` in Indy), but I intentionally changed the `TIdSMTP.UseTLS` to `utUseImlicitTLS` to simulate a TLS negotiation failure.

In the first `TIdSMTP.Connect()` test, I got an `EIdSocketError` exception ('**Socket Error # 10060 Connection timed out**') instead of a TLS negotiation failed message/exception. In this test, the only triggered events were `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.OnStatus` and `TIdSMTP.OnStatus`.

In the second `TIdSMTP.Connect()` test, I don't receive the `EIdSocketError` with timeout message, and aside from the events on the first try, it also triggered the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.OnStatusInfo` and `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.OnStatusInfoEx` events, handling TLS connection error.

Some code snippet:

```pascal
procedure Connect;
var
  LSMTP: TIdSMTP;
  LSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  LSMTP:= TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
  LSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  
  {functions to be declared}
  LSMTP.OnTLSNotAvailable   := MyTLSNotAvailable;
  LSMTP.OnTLSHandShakeFailed:= MyTLSHandShakeFailed;
  LSMTP.OnTLSNegCmdFailed   := MyTLSNegCmdFailed;
  LSMTP.OnFailedEHLO        := MyFailedEHLO;

  LSSL.OnStatus      := MyOnStatus;
  LSSL.OnStatusInfo  := MySSLInfo;
  LSSL.OnStatusInfoEx:= MySSlInfoEx;
  LSSL.ConnectTimeout:= 1000000;
  LSSL.ReadTimeout   := 1000000;

  LSMTP.IOHandler       := FSSL;
  LSMTP.AuthType        := satDefault;
  LSMTP.UseTLS          := utUseExplicitTLS;
  LSSL.SSLOptions.Method:= sslvSSLv23;
  LSSL.SSLOptions.Mode  := sslmBoth;

  LSMTP.Host:= 'smtp.office365.com';
  LSMTP.Port:= '587';
  LSMTP.Username:= mail@example.com;
  LSMTP.Password:= password;
  LSMTP.From:= LSMTP.Username;

  try
    LSMTP.Connect;
  except
      raise Exception.Create(Format('Error during connect attempt: %s',[Exception(ExceptObject).Message]));
  end;

end;
```

So, I have some questions:

- Why don't the `TIdSMTP.OnTLSNotAvailable`, `TIdSMTP.OnTLSHandShakeFailed`, and `TIdSMTP.OnTLSNegCmdFailed` events trigger in those cases?
- Why do the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.OnStatusInfo` and `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.OnStatusInfoEx` events trigger only in the second connection try?

Am I missing something?

Comment: This is clearly not a copy/paste of your real code, because there are several syntax errors that won't compile. Also, you should nit being use `LSSL.SSLOptions.Method` at all, use `LSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions` instead. And `LSSL.SSLOptions.Mode` should be `sslmClient`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use events to accomplish what you are attempting, as  Indy is not event-driven.  Events are for informational purposes only, not for flow control.  If the TLS handshake fails, an exception will be raised accordingly.  Catch the exception, close the TCP connection, and retry as needed.

As for your attempt to simulate a TLS failure:

- If you use `utUseImplicitTLS` on a non-tls or explicit-tls SMTP port, the client will send a TLS handshake immediately upon establishing the TCP connection, and then fail the TLS handshake when it misinterprets the server's unencrypted SMTP greeting as-if it were a TLS handshake response.
- If you use `utUseExplicitTLS` on an implicit-tls port, the client will timeout (or deadlock if you don't use a timeout) after establishing the TCP connection, because it will be waiting for an unencrypted SMTP greeting that the server never sends, because the server is waiting for a TLS handshake that the client never sends.

Regarding the various events that are available:

- `OnTLSNotAvailable` is fired when:

  - `UseTLS` is `utUseRequireTLS` <sup>1</sup>, and
  - `UseEhlo` is `True`, and
  - the SMTP server does not advertise support for `STARTTLS` when the client sends an `EHLO` command to learn the server's capabilities.

  If the event handler sets the `VContinue` parameter to `False` then an `EIdTLSClientTLSNotAvailable` exception is raised, otherwise the SMTP session continues unencrypted.  The default is `True`.

  <sup>1</sup>: On the client side, `utUseRequireTLS` is similar to `utUseExplicitTLS`, but a server's refusal to use TLS is not acceptable. Whereas TLS is optional with `utUseExplicitTLS`.
- `OnTLSHandShakeFailed` is fired when:

  - `UseTLS` is `utUseImplicitTLS` or `utUseExplicitTLS` (not `utUseRequireTLS`), and
  - the `SSLIOHandler` raises an exception during the TLS handshake.

  If the event handler sets the `VContinue` parameter to `False` then an `EIdTLSClientTLSHandShakeFailed` exception is raised, otherwise the SMTP session continues unencrypted.  The default is `False`.

  NOTE: in this case, if the exception is bypassed then the SMTP session will technically be in *undefined behavior* territory, as the state of the socket's data will be unknown (was the exception raised in the middle of a packet? In between packets? Are more packets still in-flight? Etc). Unlike with the other events where the socket data is left in a well-defined state.
- `OnTLSNegCmdFailed` is fired when:

  - `UseTLS` is `utUseExplicitTLS` (not `utUseRequireTLS`), and
  - the server sends a failure response to the `STARTTLS` command before a TLS handshake begins.

  If the event handler sets the `VContinue` parameter to `False` then an `EIdTLSClientTLSNegCmdFailed` exception is raised, otherwise the SMTP session continues unencrypted.  The default is `False`.
- `OnFailedEHLO` is fired when:

  - `UseEhlo` is `True`, and
  - the server sends a failure response to the `EHLO` command.

  If the event handler sets the `VContinue` parameter to `False` then the TCP connection is closed and an `EIdSMTPReplyError` exception is raised, otherwise the SMTP session continues without knowing what the server's capabilities are.  The default is `True`.
- `OnStatus` is fired for some general-purpose component-level actions, like resolving the IP address of a hostname, connecting to a TCP port, encoding email, etc.
- `OnStatusInfo/Ex` are fired by the `SSLIOHandler` to provide status updates from the OpenSSL library during a TLS session.  Refer to OpenSSL's documentation for information about what kind of status values are provided:

  https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/SSL_CTX_set_info_callback.html